# AutoComplete drop down list highlight part of text (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, autocompletebox

I am using the standard AutoCompleteBox control in a WPF app where the user types in a query and the AutoComplete list is built and filtered as they type.  Within the drop-down list I would like to highlight the text within every list box item that matches the text the user entered.  For example if they type ap and the drop down has dap and apple then the ap in each word would be in bold while the remaining text would not be in bold.

I have all the code to actually change the correct text to bold, BUT I can never get it called at the correct time.  I can't find the correct event to call the code to do the bolding.  In order to do the bolding I traverse the VisualTreeHelper to find each TextBlock within each ListBoxItem, but I can't find the correct event to fire off this traverse.  I always end up calling it before the entire list is shown or before it is filtered so the bold text never displays.

I know my code works because if I call the traverse from the listbox selection changed event it correctly bolds the text, but that is not the interaction I am looking for because then the user has to highlight an entry to see the bold text.

What event can I handle and call this traverse from so it is AFTER the list has been filtered and displayed?  Note, the list is re-filtered each time the user enters another character into the search box.

Thanks for any help as this is frustrating me beyond belief!